# How to use T-SQL to properly add new columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alter-table

I am getting started with T-SQL in Visual Studios 2013 and I was wondering how can you add new columns to an existing database table?

I have this snippet

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Articles]
ADD COLUMNS
  TenLatMin  FLOAT     NULL,
  TenLatMax  FLOAT     NULL,
  TenLonMin  FLOAT     NULL,
  TenLonMax  FLOAT     NULL;
```

but it complains

> incorrect syntax near FLOAT

What can be wrong about the code above?

Comment: You should try the documentation first, before just making up your own syntax, throwing your hands in the air when it doesn't work, and then asking us how DARE this made up syntax not work?

Answer (score 7):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx), you shouldn't have `COLUMNS` in there:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Articles]
ADD
TenLatMin  FLOAT     NULL,
TenLatMax  FLOAT     NULL,
TenLonMin  FLOAT     NULL,
TenLonMax  FLOAT     NULL;
```